# React-native: can't have react (web version) as dependency

Tags: react-native

When using react-native, if i have the web version of react inside `node_modules` i got this error

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object
(evaluating 'require('BatchedBridge').flushedQueue')
{"line":1, "column":25}
```

Is there an workaround for this? I want to have react and react-native installed on the same repository

Comment: Are you using require('react') anywhere? That won't work in RN.

Comment: Hmm, getting this on a fresh project after doing cmd+R. Also seeing this in the log: line: 1717
 message: Can't find variable: process", {"line":1717,"column":28,"sourceURL":"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle"}