# React Native : undefined is not an Object (evaluation require('BatchedBridge') Error

Tags: react-native

I have the same error message than [React-native: can't have react (web version) as dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441951/react-native-cant-have-react-web-version-as-dependency) but in my case i am using an unmodified startup project as per official React Native tutorial. 
The error message is :

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'require('BatchedBridge').flushedQueue')(line 1 in the generated bundle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for it to work you have to run both
1°) react-native start
2°) react-native run-android